# Using autocomplete live() with _renderItem not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've been all morning stuck on this: I want to use autocomplete dynamically, and I need to call _renderItem to show all items the server is returning. I had a code working perfectly statically. Now I need the web to be more flexible solution that brings dynamically this part to the DOM. I've changed what I thought it would work...but it doesn't. This is my code simplified:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var site_id = 'site_id';

// Use the .autocomplete() method to compile the list based on input from user
$('#itemCode').livequery( function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: 'include/autocompletado_promos.php?site_id=' + site_id,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            return false;
        }
    });

}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    alert("works!");

});
```

What's wrong there? thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ok, Ive realised what I was doing wrong again and again, this is the final code working:

```
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: 'include/autocompletado_promos.php?site_id=' + site_id,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            return false;
        }
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
         alert("works!");
    };
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you changed?

Comment: He had originally attached `.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem` to `livequery` instead of `autocomplete`.